# boot versus register method in laravel service provider

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, service, boot

I am confused in this terminlogy because i am not able to differentiate between these two methods as they seems same to me .
I have also read the documentation and i got the following lines which says

register method is for registering class while boot method triggers something .

lets take this example

```
    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind('someHelperClass', function () {
            return new SomeClass();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('App\Services\Internal\User\UserService', function ($app) {
            return new UserService();
        });
    }
```

there is register method and boot method one is for someClass binding and other one is for userservice instantiation

I just want to know what this two bindings will do and what difference is there also what if I put all bindings in register method or boot method.

Comment: boot method is called after the registration of all other service providers. So if you want to do something which may use other service provider's service, you should do it in the boot method, because all other services is being registered already.

Comment: the 'singleton' would go in the `register` method as well, as something else may need that binding to exist ... bindings go in the `register` method

Comment: @lagbox, I also didn't find in the docs something that says the same and this question turned up when I started googling but probably it is because it was obvious? But it actually is a bit tricky. I wonder why all the example bindings in the https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container page are written as if they are on a blank file. Not mentioning the class or method they are written in. The laravel docs are great otherwise and elsewhere.